# using alias for cast in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, casting, group-by, hive, alias

I have a table called loan with loan amount,annual income, year (MMM-YY format) and member id. I am trying to find the highest loan amount in a year along wit annual income and member id details.

I tried to group the highest loan amount by year using the code

```
select max(cast(loan_amt as int)),issue_d from loan group by issue_d;
```

then I wanted also to fetch the member id and annual income information so I wrote the following code

but it is giving me error message for using alias for a column which is cast.

Code:

```
select a.loan_amt,a.member_id,a.annual_inc,a.issue_d
from 
(select loan_amt,member_id,annual_inc,issue_d from loan) a
join
(select max(cast(loan_amt as int)) as ml,issue_d from loan group by issue_d) c
where ((a.issue_d=c.issue_d) and (a.loan_amt=a.ml));
```

Comment: Is your code actually using on instead of where and c.ml in the second join condition ?

Comment: You are asking to technically fix a bad solution instead of asking for a good solution.

Comment: P.s. MMM-YY is a bad design and so is loan_amt that need to be cast.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is **rank** the records based on the Amount, per Period, then keep only the top 1 record for each Period.
Use one of the [analytic functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) that are designed exactly for that purpose -- Hive has a pretty good support of the SQL standard on that topic.

Since you don't say what to do about ties (i.e. what if several loans have the same Amount???) I assume you want just one record chosen *randomly*...

```
select X, Y, Z, Period, Amount as TopAmount
from
 (select X, Y, Z, Period, cast(StrAmt as double) as Amount,
    row_number() over (partition by Period order by cast(StrAmt as double) desc) as TmpRank
  from WTF
 ) TMPWTF
where TmpRank =1
```

If you want *all* the records with top Amount then replace `row_number` with `rank` or `dense_rank` (the "dense" stuff would make a difference for the top 2, but not for the top 1)